# Locating elements with Selenium webdriver Css contain text

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with locating object by cssSelector and text contain

I have

```
<lc-detail class="ng-isolate-scope" prefix="lifeType" value="::vm.life.type" label="Life Type">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        <label class="col-sm-4 select-all ng-binding">Life Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-control-static select-all ng-binding" ng-bind-html="::valueTranslated" style="padding-top:0">
            Message
        </div>
    </div>
</lc-detail>
```

I must click on last div (text) but only lc-detail.. is unique and text "Message" is unique

i have but does't work

```
By.cssSelector("[label='Life Type'] [contains('Message')]"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is target `div` inside or above `lc-detail`?

Comment: can you use xpath? If yes, try this: `//lc-detail//div[text()='Message']`. It returns div with text "Message", which is inside `lc-detail`

Comment: @kotoj //lc-detail//div[text()='Message'] work's super, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath instead of css selector:

`By.xpath("//lc-detail//div[text()='Message']")`